# Forcing New Browser Window when clicking on web link in an email (Outlook Desktop App)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Just wondering if there is a registry hack or some other easy way I can get Outlook Desktop app (2016, 2019, 365, etc.) to open a new web browser window (instead of a new tab in an existing window) when I click a hyperlink in an email?  I'm using Chrome as my default browser although probably switching to Edge shortly, although hopefully any registry edit or other change will work on whatever I use as my default browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opnion, it may be related to the browse settings. According to my experience in Chrome, we could set the register like below to meet it:

Location: *Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command*

Value : Default

change the value data to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --new-window "%1"
```

Comment: Hi @Marc NJ, have you tried this register value?

Comment: Wouldn't that change the functionality of Chrome across the board?  I just want to change it so that within Outlook when you click on a hyperlink it launches a new window - not for every other hyperlink.  For instance, in Chrome, when hold down CTRL + click link, it opens in new tab.  Would that now cause a new window to open after changing the above?  Thanks.

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't affect any links in Chrome. It's just a global setting for the links from other programs(including Outlook, Word etc.), but we couldn't set it for Outlook only.

Comment: So weirdly enough something (on two separate computers where I've implemented this) keeps reverting this registry value back to default - no idea what is causing it.  Any thoughts/suggestions?